# Software testing - Which of the following sets of values will achieve 100% decision coverage with the least number of test cases?

Tags: testing

Consider the following high level program design and assume you can
provide the values for `today`, `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
Start;
While B < C
  If today = Monday
     set A = 1
  elseif today = Wednesday
     set A = 2
  Endif;
  If B < C
     B = B + 1
  Endif;
Endwhile;
End;
```

Which of the following sets of values will achieve 100% decision coverage with
the least number of test cases (the order of the values is `today`, `A`, `B`, `C`)?

a. Monday, 1, 3, 3; Monday 3, 2, 4; Wednesday, 1, 2, 3; Tuesday, 5, 3, 4

b. Monday, 1, 2, 4; Wednesday 1, 2, 4

c. Monday, 5, 1, 1; Tuesday, 5, 1, 2; Wednesday, 5, 1, 2

d. Monday, 5, 3, 2; Monday, 5, 1, 1; Monday 5, 2, 3; Tuesday, 4, 4, 3;
Wednesday, 1, 2, 3

I looked up the answer and it is a., but HOW? Can someone PLEASE explain this to me in the simplest terms possible? I don't understand it at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decisions in that code are

- `B < C` #1
- `today = Monday`
- `today = Wednesday`
- `B < C` #2

Let's ignore the second `B < C` for now.

All but the first decision can only be reached if the first decision is true. To exit each decision both ways you need all of the following to be true in some test case:

- `B < C` is false
- `B < C` is true and `today = Monday`
- `B < C` is true and `today = Wednesday`
- `B < C` is true and `today =` anything other than `Monday` or `Wednesday`

Test cases that allow this are

1. any `B` and `C` such that `B >= C`, other values don't matter
2. any `B` and `C` such that `B < C`, `today = Monday`
3. any `B` and `C` such that `B < C`, `today = Wednesday`
4. any `B` and `C` such that `B < C`, `today =` anything other than `Monday` or `Wednesday`

The list of test cases in "a" satisfies those four sets of criteria. It's probably not a coincidence that they're in the order I came up with them.

`A` never matters at all, because `A` isn't used in any decision.

Back to that second `B < C`: `B` must be less than `C` to reach that decision, so if we reach that decision we'll always take its `B < C` branch. However, we can *never* take its `B >= C` branch. The four test cases are the best we can do, but we can never reach 100% decision coverage! The analysis tells us that the code has problems, in this case that the second check for `B < C` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's a mistake on the question.
The actual question is:**
 Consider the following high-level program design and assume you can
provide the values for today, A, B and C:

```
Start;
Do until B = C
  If today = Monday
     set A = 1
   elseif today = Wednesday
    Set A = 2
    Set B = C
   Endif;
   If B < C
      B = B + 1
   Endif;
Endloop;
End;
```

Which of the following sets of values will achieve **100% decision coverage** with the least number of test cases (the order of the values is today, A, B, C)?

```
a. Monday, 1, 3, 3; Monday 3, 2, 4; Wednesday, 1, 2, 3; Tuesday, 5, 4, 3
b. Monday, 1, 2, 4; Wednesday 1, 2, 4
c. Monday, 5, 1, 1; Tuesday, 5, 1, 2; Wednesday, 5, 1, 2
d. Monday, 5, 3, 2; Monday, 5, 1, 1; Monday 5, 2, 3; Tuesday, 4, 4, 3;
Wednesday, 1, 2, 3
```

a. is the right answer, explanation: Monday 1.3.3 cover decision "Set = 1"

Monday       3.2.4 cover decision "If B < C and B = B + 1" since it's right 2<4
Wednesday 1.2.3 cover decisions (True Path) Set A = 2 and Set B = C
Tuesday       5,4,3 cover decisions (Flase Path)
(Only Monday and Wednesday input data can break the loop)

[image]